# Why does bundle install add a binstub of itself (bundle) which can't be executed?

Tags: bundler, rbenv

I have a simple Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'librarian-puppet'
gem 'onceover'
```

When I install this using bundle (through rbenv shim: `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`) then binstubs are installed in `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin`. But I can't execute them directly, for all I get the same result:

```sh
$ vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/onceover
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/onceover:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /opt/puppetlabs/pdk/private/ruby/2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
/opt/puppetlabs/pdk/private/ruby/2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem onceover (>= 0.a) with executable onceover (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

However, if I execute these binstubs using (rbenv shimmed) `bundle exec` then it works:

```sh
$ bundle exec onceover --help
...
```

So this is fine – although I'm not sure if it's expected, I'm a Ruby newbie.

But what confuses me is that one of the binstubs is `bundle` itself. Which would seems silly, since that only way to run it is `bundle exec bundle` which does work:

```sh
$ bundle exec bundle --version
Bundler version 2.1.4
```

However. This causes problems for me in IntelliJ IDEA, which when executing using `bundle` finds the binstubbed version and uses that. If I `rm vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/bundle` then it falls back to the rbenv shimmed version and is fine.

Finally, my question. Assuming this isn't wrong from the start, why does bundle install a binstub of itself? I have found other `vendor` directories where this did not seem to happen but I can't figure out the mechanism that causes the difference.